# I am getting double input on my controller

Tags: controllers

In the past I was using an Xbox One controller which is 3 years old on my laptop which has Windows 10. I connected the controller to the laptop by using a USB cable. In the last year I started getting double input when I pressed the A button when I am playing non steam games.

I got fed up of the double input issue and I bought an 8bitdo sn30 pro+ 3 months ago, and I set it to XInput mode and I connected it to my laptop by using a USB cable. The firmware version is 5.02. I am still getting double input when I press the B button when I am playing non steam games (pressing B gives A in a game). It is happening randomly and unexpectedly and I can't properly duplicate the double input.

I was suspecting that enabling Xbox support in steam and steam rumble is causing the double input so I disabled both, but the problem is still happening.

I got double input in 2 controllers in a row, thus I think it's a software issue. Is steam causing double input and it can happen with Xbox support disabled and enabled or is it a controller issue?

I want to ask that is there anyone else who is getting double input with the 8bitdo sn30 pro+ when it is on XInput mode? If yes then have you figured out why the double input is happening?

I just set my controller to switch mode and I enabled switch support in steam and I added the game that I am playing to steam.

Will setting the controller to switch mode stop the double input?

Comment: If you're using Controller Support through Steam, consider turning it off. It's possible the game is receiving input from the controller and Steam at the same time.

Comment: i turned it off. i still got double input